# Pressing tab key is not redirecting to correct textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three text box A,B, and C. By default B text box is disabled and is enabled only when there is some value present in A.

When the user enters any value in A and press tab key, then B is enabled as expected but the flow due to tab is transferred to C instead of B.

```
function enableOrDisableTaxThresholdAmount(elm,taxThresholdAmountField){
    if($(elm).val() != "") {
    $(elm).closest('.fieldRowtest').find('[name="'+B+'"]').prop('disabled',false).removeClass('editboxdisabled'); 
    } else {
    $(elm).closest('.fieldRowtest').find('[name="'+B+'"]').val('').prop('disabled',true).addClass('editboxdisabled');
           }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a working example please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jquery .focus(), for example you can overload [Tab]button click:

```
$("A").keydown(function(event){if(event.keyCode == <TABCODE>) {event.preventDefault();$("B").prop("disabled", false);$("B").focus();}});
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try by giving tabindex to input fields

```
<input tabindex=1 />    <input tabindex=2 />    <input tabindex=3 />
```